# Listing ol li up to down in 2 column with CSS

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have an `ol`/`li` listing (in one `ol` tag), I need to list in two columns. There must be a way to do it in CSS.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have no definite answer for you, but you may have a look at this article from "A List Apart": [CSS Swag: Multi-Column Lists](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/multicolumnlists/).

There are listed several methods to achieve this, but only some of them work with *one single* list.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the start attribute

```html
<ol>
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
</ol> 

<ol start="4">
  <li>Four</li>
  <li>Five</li>
  <li>Six</li>
</ol>
```

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_ol_start.asp